# How can I use PHP codes in a javascript tag?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use php in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851995/can-i-use-php-in-javascript)

I want to assign the value of variable "i"(javascript) to the variable $x(PHP). 
below code doesnt work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

 for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
    d1.push([i, <?php $x=" ?>i<?php "; echo test($x); ?>]);
.
.
.
```

Comment: not possible, you have to use ajax. PHP is serverside, JS is clientside. PHP is finished after your page is rendered, you can not change it with JS which is just starting after your page is rendered

Comment: you cant do that. Google about AJAX

Comment: you can't assign javascript value(variable) to a php variable

Comment: you CANNOT assign php variables in javascript like that! the php code will run on the server, but the js one runs on the client side, so this wil just throw you an error, if you explain what ure trying to do maybe there will be other ways to do it

Comment: You could go for the alternative - jQuery + AJAX. That would make your job much easier. It's not that hard either. Here is a tutorial in case you want to know more - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0):

But PHP is *serverside*, so is parsed before the JavaScript ever realises it's there... you need to save the PHP variable into some sort of JS datastructure before the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP code to produce JavaScript which is then served to the user.
The other way around (using JavaScript to create PHP code or inject values there) is not possible directly.

One exception here is, that you may use AJAX requests to execute another PHP script on the server. Inside that request you may include some values generated by JavaScript to pass them on to the PHP script.

In general PHP is the serverside language whereas JavaScript is on the client's side. You can generate the client's code on the server side, but not vice verse.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it doesn't work.  What your code is doing is assigning the PHP variable `$x` the literal string value of `" ?>i<?php "`.  You can't escape from PHP mode in the middle of a string literal.

You seem to be misunderstanding certain fundamentals of how the client/server model of web applications work.  JavaScript is run at the client (in the browser), PHP on the server.  The client should never see any PHP code and the server will never execute any JavaScript code.  You can't mix and match (without using AJAX, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You could $_POST the variable contents to the server (through a form). Otherwise you'll have to use AJAX to post the variable to the server.

Either way, you need to take it from the client and send it server-side.